# Конкретные теги нужно использовать в странице HTML, чтобы браузер FireFox начал считать это поисковой системой и предложил её добавить в избранные?

Tags: поиск, firefox

Решения исключённые:

1. В браузера настройках, нет предложений добавлять поисковую систему
2. При посещенииии сделанной страницы HTML нет предложений добавлять поисковые системы.

Comment: > В браузера настройках, нет предложений добавлять поисковую систему - то есть, добавить поисковую систему через настройки браузера - этот варант Вам не подходит?

Comment: Речь идёт про добавление локальных поисковых систеv (поднятых например на Apache PHP) конкретного искать, это массивы численные очень, например справки, маршрутизация поисковиков и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Решение: В about:config сделать browser.urlbar.update2.engineAliasRefresh=true.Далее на страницы настроек->Поиск, появилась секретное спасение от пытки "Кнопка Добавить".

Comment: вопрос-то был про некие волшебные «теги».